# Runtime Error 1004 when running a code on a sheet created dynamically

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2010

I am using excel 2010 and I wrote this code in one Workbook:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim flname As Variant, n As Variant

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D5:H20")) Is Nothing Then
        flname = Application.GetOpenFilename
        If flname <> False Then
            If Right(flname, 3) = "jpg" Then

                Set n = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(flname)
                n.Name = "Picture 1"
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4).Left
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4).Top
                n.Width = 270
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
                Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 10
                Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 2

            Else

                MsgBox "Das Bild muss ein JPEG-Format sein"

            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

And it works perfectly fine on any Sheet of this, or other Workbooks, but when I try to run it on a Sheet that was dynamically created the VBA returns me an Error (1004) and highlights this line:

```
Set n = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(flname)
```

I searched on internet but coulnd find any topic about 1004 errors on dynamically created Sheets.

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance for you  help!

Kind regards,
Hugo.

Comment: did you try activating newly created sheet before before running this code?  I can't remember if creating a sheet actually activates it or not...I guess I could go try it.

Comment: @sous2817 Yes i did. The newly created Sheet is active when this code runs.

Comment: How did you add this code to the newly created sheet?

Comment: Is there is a line between the If and the Set statement that activates (or creates) a new sheet?

Comment: What is in flname when you get the error?

Comment: Just figured it out! I am really dumb, sorry for making you lose your time and thank for all the support. The problem was that the code that I use to create the new sheets lock them at the end.The range where this code works ("D5:H20") is unlocked by this same code but it looks like even when it is unprotected I can't insert images to this Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the code I was using to generate Sheets was locking them as well. I thought that unlocking the Range that was associated to the code would make it works, the problem was that when you insert an image it is not contained in a cell or a Range of cells it basically "floats" on the Sheet so the image could not be inserted because the Sheet was locked and that's the reason I got the error 1004 and the highlighted line was

```
Set n = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(flname)
```

Because that was the action that inserted the image in the Sheet.

The solution is quite simple you just need to unlock the Sheet at the begining of the  code (or just above the line you insert the image) with this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Your Passoword"
```

And at the end if you want to lock it again you add this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Your Password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

I hope my answer was clear enough.
Thanks for everyone that tried to help me with this.

Kind regards,
Hugo.